# How to query for TOP 10, AVG with Distinct Values

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the top 10 results from the highest average while grouping together

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPRX.png)

Comment: Hint:  It starts with `SELECT`.

Comment: ... follows with 'TOP'.

Comment: dear... people here will be resilient to help you unless they see you put an effort. Show your query and state what issues you have with it. also, read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Comment: `GROUP BY` for grouping.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP(10) column1, 
              avg(column2)
FROM  TableName
Group By column1
Order By avg(column2) DESC
```